# How to drive MOSFET with 2.7v?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, mosfet, drone, quad-copter

Okay, I have mini coreless motor drone. I want to make a bigger drone by replacing the corless motor with 180 motor. For that, I need to control 4 MOSFETs to drive four 180 motors. Here comes my question - how can I drive those FETs?  I've tried connecting the gate signals which are already fed to the gate of the internal MOSFETs (9926a Dual MOSFET) for driving the coreless motors to my IRFZ44N (I only have these) MOSFETs gate. But the signal voltage is too low for my MOSFETs. So then I tried connecting the signals to an arduino and tried to map them from 0 to 5v which is suitable for IRFZ44N, but it didn’t work. I don't know why.
Any idea how I can drive my MOSFETs with the signal. When I pull the throttle a little bit the signal read 0.5v and 2.7v at maximum throttle.

Comment: How much current are you trying to permit your motors to have? What supply voltage do the motors runs from? What is "180 motor" - does not compute etc.. 2.7 volts won't get you anywhere with an IRFZ44 MOSFET. Hint - saying something doesn't work is hiding from us what actually happened.

Comment: Sounds like you'll need a gate driver, but that's really all I can really suggest since there's no schematic or motor specs.

Comment: Get MOSFETs with RDSon rated for 2.5V. IRFZ44N is rated  for Vgs = 10V and no lower.

Comment: Youll probably have more practical result if you go on rcgroups and see what FETs people are using for upgrades.  You'll want something matching the form factor of your board.  Depending on your motor you may need to design a brushed ESC (lots of practical write-ups on that too) but most would go brushless.  Realize this will be more dangerous when it gets large and more regulation will typically then apply.  You'll also need to change PID gains so don't bother with this on a board you are not already reflashing with open firmware (also commonly discussed there...)

Comment: Andy Aka 180 motor draws about 4 amps of current at 7.4 volt. And I'm not hiding anything.

Comment: bunker89320 my motor draws 4 amps at 7.4V. Can anyone suggest any mosfet gate driver for that?